# Ubuntu 20.04 memory leak with Docker and Tomcat 9

Tags: docker, ubuntu, elasticsearch, tomcat

My setup is as follows:

Ubuntu 20.04 server (16GB RAM) which runs Docker and Elasticsearch 6.8.16 image in a container with following env values -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g".

It also hosts two apps on Tomcat 9, and I have also set up these envs for Tomcat via setenv.sh in Tomcat's bin folder.

However, after a few hours, my remaining memory is less than 100MB and it happens every day. It stabilizes after I reboot the server, but after a few hours it falls under 100MB again.

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

If anyone needs any additional information, I am more than happy to provide it.

P.S. For some reason, my CPU always has 100% usage on one core while the other one is below 10%.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @dratenik The app becomes extremely unresponsive and I check the memory with "free -m" command.

Comment: @dratenik Here you go: https://imgur.com/dNeaBbK

Comment: @dratenik "Available" goes below 100.

Comment: We got there in the end. Ok, "available" is the right number to look at. (classic mistake: looking at the "free" number).

Comment: Next step: figuring out which process is eating memory and CPU. If the java VM is limited to 2G, it's unlikely to be the culprit for memory. Get a shell into the running docker and look at `top` (pressing M reorders it by memory usage)?

Comment: If the java VM needs more than 2G, it will thrash about, trying to garbage collect its way out of the problem, so it could be eating the CPU. [tips for debugging java GC](https://www.baeldung.com/java-verbose-gc)

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/sXnhYp3 @dratenik
I run docker with this command:
docker run -d --restart=always -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g"  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.16

Comment: The time to collect that information is when you have 100 MB available and 100 % CPU usage.

Comment: @dratenik Here it is when available memory is 42mb. https://imgur.com/FlKgNXt